# How can I change a file date in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

In Windows/AIR/Flex I have a scenario where I download a file from a server, currently using FileStream, and I need the file to have the same modification date/time on the client computer as the web server. The file gets created on the client with the then current date/time.

I am already sending the date of the file on the web server for a different purpose. I have reviewed the documentation for File & FileStream and cannot see a property or method which would allow me to create a file with a specific date, or modify a file's modification date.

Is anyone aware of this capability in AIR? (v32.0)

Edit:

The purpose of this is to check to see if the file I have locally is the same as the file on the web server. I currently check the dates on both sides, but the date of the downloaded and it is set to the date/time it was downloaded. I would like it to be the date/time it was created on the file server.

Comment: How big is this file to check (in megabytes)? Alternate options include... **(1)** A basic bytes compare, since any newly updated version on server won't have the same exact bytes as what users have already downloaded previously. **(2)** Create your own file format as a  container (eg: first 10 bytes is a header which holds your own info like a version number or date, then following is the actual file bytes). **(3)** Use some Checksum CRC or MD5 checking for _"similarity"_ but I think it's too much effort for just one file. Options **1** or **2** are best for your described problem.

Comment: Actually, you can keep some kind of registry locally (**SharedObject** or another file) and store the file version there. Then you first ask server for the file modification date to compare it to the local value. If the versions differ, you download and save the file then finally update the registry. What **VC.One** suggests is also true, but I think he's overthinking it. You don't need any of that **unless** you actually want to **verify** the local content.

Comment: @Organis Why involve storing a second separate file (of bytes) to hold the date or version number when those same bytes could just be pasted into the main file itself? My **Option 1** takes less than 1 second to scan _eg:_ 30 million bytes. **Option 2** avoids saving any extra files elsewhere because that same info is **embedded** at the start (or ending) of their file. Consider how MP3 file does not also save a separate JPG or text file for the cover art and title info. Not 3 separate files only 1 & extract what you want (text, photo or audio). Here they can extract embedded date or version.

Comment: @VC.One Because my way is more efficient performance-wise and simpler in general: it can be scaled up for multiple files case and it can be ported to devices with far less CPU power. I don't say your ideas won't work, but they have flaws. Your **(1)** is pointless because if you download the file anyway, why bother with the local copy? Your **(2)** works for custom data format only, if you add anything to the file, you make it unusable for any common data or image or content format. Your **(3)** requires abundance of CPU processing power which could be not available on mobile devices.

Comment: I had intended to eventually get around to using a hash to check whether the files are the same anyway. This just moves up the schedule. I will be posting another question, because my ,NET & AS3 MD5 hashes for the same file are different.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't change the creation date or modification date. you can check for the modification date using f.modificationDate.getTime()  and compare it to something you already have

There is no api in AIR to change the creation date or modification date.

Comment: I was afraid of that. See edit explaining what I am doing above.

Comment: In the past, in order to achieve similar functionality, I save the dates in the file (like created, modified) or to a local database (you can use sqlite or sharedprefs) then compare these.